# Running an animation when a particular child element is clicked, but doing nothing on all other children

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, javascript-objects

I am attempting to get the following code snippet to work the way I want it to. I only want the sub-menu to slide back to the right when the "li" element with the class "back" is selected. Right now, when any element is clicked, the sub-menu slides back to the right. I have tried the following code to no avail, but believe it is sort of on the right track:

```
$(function() {
 $('.section').click( function() {
 $(this).find('ul').animate( {
    left: "0"
 }, 1000 );
 }).children().click( function() {

var selected = this;
console.debug(selected);

if ($(this).hasClass("back")) {
    $('.sub-menu').animate( {
        left: "485"
    }, 1000 );
}
else {
    return false;
   }
 });
});
```

I believe that it isn't recognizing the nested LI element with the class "back" as being any different then the original "sub-menu" ul. I also tried

```
.children(":not(.back)").click( function() {
    return false;
}
```

Which did not work.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.section').click( function() {
    $(this).find('ul').animate( {
     left: "0"
    }, 1000 );
  }).children().click( function() {
 $('.sub-menu').animate( {
     left: "485"
    }, 1000 );

    return false;

  });
});
```

```css
ul {
 margin: 0;
 padding:0;
 list-style-type: none;
}

li {
 background-color: green;
 color: white;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
 width: 100%;
 height: 20px;
 font-size: 16px;
 text-align: center;
}

a {
 display: block;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 color: #fff;
}
.container {
 margin: auto;
 max-width:480px;
 width: 480px;
 height: 736px;
 border: 1px solid black;
 overflow-x: visible;
 position: relative;
}

.menu {
 position: relative;
 z-index: 1;
}
.main-menu {
 position: relative;
}
.sub-menu {
 position: absolute;
 z-index:2;
 width: 100%;
 display: inline;
 left: 485px;
 top: 0;
}
.sub-menu li {
 background-color: blue !important;
}
.hidden {
 display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
 <div class="menu">
  <ul class="main-menu">
   <li class="section">
    Section 1
    <ul class="sub-menu" style="z-index: 3;">
     <li>
      <a href="#section1a">Section 1A</a>
     </li>
     <li>
      <a href="#section1b">Section 1B</a>
     </li>
     <li>
      <a href="#section1c">Section 1C</a>
     </li>
     <li class="back">
      Back
     </li>
    </ul>
   </li>
   <li class="section">
    Section 2
    <ul class="sub-menu" style="z-index: 2;">
     <li>
      Section 2A
     </li>
     <li>
      Section 2B
     </li>
     <li>
      Section 2C
     </li>
     <li class="back">
      Back
     </li>
    </ul>
   </li>
         </ul>
       </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: You can change `.children().click(....)` to `.find(".back").click(....)` because `children()` will select the `ul` element not the `li`s.

Comment: Ah man, so quick... you the man.

Answer (score 1):

You can change `.children().click(....)` to `.find(".back").click(....)` because `children()` will select the `ul` element not the `li`s.

This should work.

```
$(function() {
 $('.section').click( function() {
     $(this).find('ul').animate( {
        left: "0"
     }, 1000 );
  }).find(".back").click( function() {
    $(this).parent().animate( {
        left: "485"
    }, 1000 );
 });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have a jquery click on `back` that animates the parent.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.section').click( function() {
    $(this).find('ul').animate( {
     left: "0"
    }, 1000 );
  })
$('.back').click( function() {
 $(this).parent().animate( {
     left: "485"
    }, 1000 );

    return false;

  });
});
```

```css
ul {
 margin: 0;
 padding:0;
 list-style-type: none;
}

li {
 background-color: green;
 color: white;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
 width: 100%;
 height: 20px;
 font-size: 16px;
 text-align: center;
}

a {
 display: block;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 color: #fff;
}
.container {
 margin: auto;
 max-width:480px;
 width: 480px;
 height: 736px;
 border: 1px solid black;
 overflow-x: visible;
 position: relative;
}

.menu {
 position: relative;
 z-index: 1;
}
.main-menu {
 position: relative;
}
.sub-menu {
 position: absolute;
 z-index:2;
 width: 100%;
 display: inline;
 left: 485px;
 top: 0;
}
.sub-menu li {
 background-color: blue !important;
}
.hidden {
 display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
 <div class="menu">
  <ul class="main-menu">
   <li class="section">
    Section 1
    <ul class="sub-menu" style="z-index: 3;">
     <li>
      <a href="#section1a">Section 1A</a>
     </li>
     <li>
      <a href="#section1b">Section 1B</a>
     </li>
     <li>
      <a href="#section1c">Section 1C</a>
     </li>
     <li class="back">
      Back
     </li>
    </ul>
   </li>
   <li class="section">
    Section 2
    <ul class="sub-menu" style="z-index: 2;">
     <li>
      Section 2A
     </li>
     <li>
      Section 2B
     </li>
     <li>
      Section 2C
     </li>
     <li class="back">
      Back
     </li>
    </ul>
   </li>
         </ul>
       </div>
   </div>
```